# Adding Extended Property in SQL Server by a loop

Tags: sql-server

I have a table below **ExtendedProperties**

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DatabaseName | SchemaName | TableName | ColumnName | Description         | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| database1    |  dbo       |  Users    |   UserId   | this is user id     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| database1    |  dbo       |  Users    |   name     | this is user name   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| database2    | dbo        |  Comments | CommentId  | this is id          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| database2    | dbo        |  Comments | Description| this is description |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The table contains over 200 entries.

Instead of going each column in SQL Server Management Studio and entering those Description I would like to write a loop to automatically create each column extended property.

For the first row the sql query is like below:

```
    USE database1
    GO
    EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Caption', 
    @value=N'this is user id' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Users', 
    @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'UserId'
```

I would like to create a loop to run this query (in C# this would be something like below)

```
foreach(var row in ExtendedProperties){

USE row.DatabaseName 
        GO
        EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Caption', 
        @value=N row.Description , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N   row.TableName, 
        @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N row.ColumnName

}
```

How can I achieve this loop in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate data row-by-row basis SQLServer has an object [`CURSOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx), but in this case I would use a dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT @dsql += 'USE [' + DatabaseName +  '] EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''Caption'',' +
       '@value=''' + [Description] + ''', @level0type=N''SCHEMA'',' +
       '@level0name=N''dbo'', @level1type=N''TABLE'', @level1name=N''' + TableName + ''',' +
       '@level2type=N''COLUMN'',@level2name=N''' + ColumnName + ''''
FROM dbo.ExtendedProperties
--PRINT @dsql
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that I can add this dynamic sql  USE [DatabaseName]?